# Profiling for wall-time on Linux

Tags: profiling, strace, systemtap

I have an application that I want to profile wrt how much time is spent in various activities. Since this application is  I/O intensive, I want to get a report that will summarize how much time is spent in every library/system call (wall time).

I've tried oprofile, but it seems it gives time in terms of Unhalted CPU cycles (thats cputime, not real time)

I've tried strace -T, which gives wall time, but the data generated is huge and getting the summary report is difficult (and awk/py scripts exist for this ?)

Now I'm looking upto SystemTap, but I don't find any script that is close enough and can be modified, and the onsite tutorial didn't help much either. I am not sure if what I am looking for can be done.

I need someone to point me in the right direction.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: As for system calls: syscalltime - Combination shell/systemtap script to measure system call counts and times.  Can be filtered by process IDs, process names and users.https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/syscalltimes

Answer (score 5):

Judging from [this commit](http://sourceforge.net/p/strace/code/ci/e53bf23f1c33076090b51184b82af4dd98d0c51c/), the [recently released strace 4.9](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/files/strace/4.9/) supports this with:

```
strace -w -c
```

They call it "syscall latency" (and it's hard to see from the manpage alone that's  what `-w` does).

Comment: This is a working solution. Can't believe this was added as late as 2014.

Comment: And I can't believe it's still not available in CentOS 7!

Comment: It's good that strace.io points to https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:ldv_alt/strace/ where they have packages for many distros

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this just out of measurement curiosity, or because you want to find time-drains that you can fix to make it run faster?

If your goal is to make it run as fast as possible, then [try random-pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).
It doesn't measure anything, except very roughly.
It may be counter-intuitive, but what it does is pinpoint the code that will result in the greatest speed-up.

Comment: speeding it up might be the eventual goal, and random pausing might be a quick way to the solution, but i would prefer to have a proper analysis that can be presented if necessary , thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

See the `fntimes.stp` systemtap sample script. https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/index.html#profiling/fntimes.stp

*The fntimes.stp script monitors the execution time history of a given function family (assumed non-recursive).  Each time (beyond a warmup interval) is then compared to the historical maximum.  If it exceeds a certain threshold (250%), a message is printed.*

```
# stap fntimes.stp 'kernel.function("sys_*")'
```

or

```
# stap fntimes.stp 'process("/path/to/your/binary").function("*")'
```

The last line of that .stp script demonstrates the way to track time consumed in a given family of functions

```
probe $1.return { elapsed = gettimeofday_us()-@entry(gettimeofday_us()) }
```